# How to get data in input field as value by Ajax request?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, ajax

```
           <h5 class="text-white"> <span id="getTitle"></span></h5> 

           <form action="#"  method="post" id="post_subform"  >               ​
      ​
          ​<input type="text" name="postid" id="getID" value="" />              
          ​<input type="text" name="postdetails" id="getPostdetails" value=""/>

          ​<input type="submit" style="background-color: red" value="confirm" id="postSubmitBtn">
```

This Form data Submit Properly, That is not my problem, I want fetch Some data in this Form through database, Here Out side of form   Data retrieve properly, But i want both input field value will be id="getID" & id="getPostdetails" value.

```
   // Here is My fetch data  in Details Ajax Request
    $("body").on("click", ".btnad","a", function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        
        var url = $(this).attr('href'); 
        window.open(url, '_blank');

        details_id = $(this).attr('id');
                
        $.ajax({
           url: 'assets/php/process.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { details_id: details_id},
            success:function(response){
                                  
               data = JSON.parse(response);
                $("#getID").text(data.id);
                $("#getTitle").text(data.post_title);                                  
                $("#getPostdetails").text(data.post_det);
                   
            }
            
        });
        
    });
```

Comment: There is no `class=btnad` in the html so not sure where that selector came from. Also have an extra `,"a"` that doesn't make sense. Overall question is not clear at all

Comment: class=btnad and a both are used for a link click than show this form and "a" for other link here onclick function i use for open two window one is self and other _blank.  I want show data in input field with value by #getID & #getPostdetails. Here outside of form #getTitle show properly input field value not work

Comment: Well if form gets submitted it reloads the page. This is very confusing. Note that you use `val()` to st value on form controls not `text()`. Also for multiple selectors in `on()` they need to be in same string like: `".btnad,a"`

Comment: Thanks for your proper suggestion, I want show data in input field value by  #getID and  #getPostdetails.